# how to hide element in angular 4 using *ng-if?

Tags: angular

I am trying to test `@Input` in angular 2 .`@Input` hide or show my `p` tag .I want to test this functionality using jasmine.

here is my component

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  @Input() enable:boolean
  constructor() { }
}
```

**testing code.**

```
describe('@Input property ', () => {
    it('will not show p tag', () => {
      component.enable = false;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      PEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p'));
      console.log(PEl.nativeElement);
      expect(PEl.nativeElement.length).toEqual(0);
    })
  })
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-wzxrin?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Comment: If you use `*ngIf` and it's false then the element will not be rendered to the dom tree. So your `PEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p'));` returns nothing... that is what you would have to check in your test.

Comment: @Fussel what is condition for that

Comment: i checked it's length is `0` but it not works for me

Comment: It has no length, it will be null

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-wzxrin?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Comment: it works for hide ..it length never `1` or greeter than `0` when if value `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if it's null, not if it has length.

```
component.enable = false;
fixture.detectChanges();
PEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p'));
console.log(PEl.nativeElement);
expect(PEl).toBeUndefined();
```

Comment: what about when enable is `true`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-wzxrin?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Comment: `expect(PEl).not.toBeUndefined()`

Comment: see your test is failing

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-wzxrin?file=app%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Answer (score 0):

Test for null not for length

```
component.enable = false;
fixture.detectChanges();
PEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p'));
expect(PEl).tobeNull();
```